# return utf-8 character inside ruby method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, axlsx

I want to return the utf-8 tick character `&#10004;` ✔ in my ruby method.

I reason I am doing it in my method is because I need that character in an excel column generated by rails axlsx.

I know we can use the content_tag to return html block tag, but not sure how I can use it to return the utf-8 character. If there is an alternative can someone please suggest me one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just return the `"✔"` String, if you have utf-8 encoded source file I'm fairly certain that works. Alternatively, you can use `"\u{codepoint}"` to return a unicode character of a specific codepoint. That codepoint in your case is [2714](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2714/index.htm) (hex), so you can do:

```
def checkmark
  "\u{2714}"
end
```

Comment: I kind of like this approach better.

Comment: one question why the number `2714` inside `{}` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Good question, I thought it was meant to be like this and worked when tested. Turns out it does not need to be :)

Answer (score 2):

That's easy:

```
def my_method
  '✔'
end
```

Comment: &#10004; ..the & symbol throws an error: unexpected &

Comment: There is no `&` in my answer, what are you talking about?